# What port state to expect from Nmap when scanning ports that are open only to specific IP addresses

Tags: nmap, whitelist

My firewall has a few ports open but traffic is only forwarded when coming from specific IP addresses (whitelisted).

When scanning these ports with nmap from a non whitelisted IP address, what state would I see those ports to be in, filtered, closed or open?

Comment: That depends on how your firewall reacts to requests coming from IP addresses that aren't included on the whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the firewall configuration, but almost every one will give back the default *Port Closed* message. If the default firewall behavior is to drop the package, it will be dropped. If is to send a `RST` package, you will receive a `RST`.

I am not aware of any firewall that responds with a *Port is open, but not for you* message.